# php array sorting by date stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, joomla, stdclass

I have an array of something  like this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 41 [title] => test2 [alias] => test2 [catid] => 8 [published] => 1 [introtext] =>
test2

[fulltext] => [video] => [gallery] => [extra_fields] => [] [extra_fields_search] => [created] => 2012-08-27 16:37:51 [created_by] => 62 [created_by_alias] => [checked_out] => 0 [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [modified_by] => 0 [publish_up] => 2012-08-27 16:37:51 [publish_down] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [trash] => 0 [access] => 1 [ordering] => 15 [featured] => 0 [featured_ordering] => 0 [image_caption] => [image_credits] => [video_caption] => [video_credits] => [hits] => 0 [params] => JParameter Object ( [_raw:protected] =>
```

and etc  in that array ( it has alot of things in it ).

Now it is displaying  like this

Item | date

Item | date

Item | date

What I want to do is  take that array and sort it by  aggregate date

Somethink like this

Aggr date

Item | date

Item | date

Aggr date

Item | date

Item | date

Is this even possible given this array ?

Comment: Do you just want to 'group by' the created date?  I don't see any measurements in the object which suggest they would be useful in an aggregate function like sum() or avg().  Are items repeated?  Guess I don't get what the 'Aggr date' is vs. the 'date' in your example desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($myArrayOfStdClasses as $key => $obj) {
    $newArray[date('Y-m-d', strtotime($obj->created]))[] = array('title' => $obj->tile, 'date' => $obj->created);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use usort to define your sorting function:

```
usort($items, function($item1, $item2){
   if($item1->created == $item2->created)
      return 0;

   return $item1->created < $item2->created ? -1 : 1;
});
```

This will just sort them.  Then on output as you loop through them you can do the aggregation based on day, hour, month however...